# Dynamically changing the neural network structure

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to implement a NEAT-like algorithm which involves dynamically changing the neural network structure like adding or deleting nodes and connections. I've been using Tensorflow for my previous work in supervised learning. But once a network is defined in Tensorflow , it cannot be changed. Is there any other framework available that provides this functionality ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's a framework designed specifically for NEAT, no, not really. The nature of symbolic execution necessarily means that there's a "create the network" step followed by a "run/train the network" step. Depending on what kind of frequency you're changing the network topology, though, Tensorflow could definitely still be viable: it will mean, every so often, saving all the parameters, and making a new model -- but this might not be terrible, depending on your parameters.

If you don't like that, you can sort of hack something together more manually using masking. That is, have some neurons "masked" out and removed, or some connnections "masked" out. You would do this by having a 0-1 valued mask for all your parameters that you pre-multiply into your parameters before applying. Keep the "allowed" connections sparse, but densely-connect everything else together as much as possible. It will, to some degree, give you slowdown since there are some additional computations, but a `tf.cond` call might be able to save you most of the time by only conditionally executing. This can't get you totally free topology evolution, but could be very flexible.